# How to change the sub-figure caption position in Quarto PDF?

Tags: r, quarto

When including subfigures in Quatro, I would like a label (without any text) at the top left side of each graph instead of below. [image]

The goal is to include the captions for the sub-figures in the "Figure 1" caption, to save space. At the same time, I want to be able to cross-reference each of the sub-figures using tags like {#fig-surus}. The export format is PDF.

```
::: {#fig-elephants layout-ncol=2}

![](surus.png){#fig-surus}

![](hanno.png){#fig-hanno}

Famous Elephants
:::
```

How can I change the sub-figure caption position in Quarto?

Comment: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64934/subfig-label-positioning) might help!